# The program does not send data to the SQL table.

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to make a dictionary. 
User input a word, tranlation, then it save in RAM like a Dict and save to Database. Problem: data is not stored in database.

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('Dictionary.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('create table if not exists Dict (WORD TEXT, TRANSLATION TEXT)')
dictionary = {}

def load_dict():
    """ From SQL transfers values ​​to RAM """
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Dict")
    while True:
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row == None: break
        dictionary[row[0]] = row[1]


def add_word():
    """ Add word to dict. """
    word = str(input('Word:'))
    translation = str(input('Translate: '))
    for key in dictionary:
        if key == word:
            print('This word is in the dictionary ')
            break
    else:
        dictionary[word] = translation
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Dict VALUES(?, ?)", (word, translation))


load_dict()
add_word()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing con.commit() after execute.

Or to automatically commit to database after execute, open connection like this:

`con = lite.connect('Dictionary.db', isolation_level=None)`

Now something for commit and rollback education. From 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

> commit()¶
>   This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.
>
> rollback()¶
>   This method rolls back any changes to the database since the last call to commit().

And controlling transactions (commit/rollback):
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions

Answer (score 1):

The reason the entries aren't being made permanent is the absence of any instruction to do so. Commit your changes permanently to the DB by adding

```
con.commit()
```

after executing the `INSERT`.

You will then find it necessary to move the inquiry about translation so the question is only asked if the word is new to the table.